# How to remove this feature from XCode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I cannot find a name for this feature and therefore I cannot figure out how to remove it. It is the mini view image that pops up in Xcode when working with Swift on the storyboard. I feel like this has to be an easy fix but I do not know how to look it up.
[Mini View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah2Jj.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called Minimap. You can toggle it using the editor menu or pressing ctrl-shift-command-M on the keyboard.

[image]